# UIDocumentPickerViewController -> "No Documents" because iCloud not available

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, uidocumentpickervc

I use this method to show an UIDocumentPicker:

```
func showDocumentPicker(){    
  let docPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.composite-content "], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
  docPicker.delegate = self
  docPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
  self.presentViewController(docPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The UIDocumentPicker gets displayed nicely, but it always shows

> No Document, Documents in iCloud Drive are not available because the iCloud Documents & Data setting is disabled

[image]

But when I check the iCloud Status, iCloud Drive is enabled! (My App even shows up in the settings there, also enabled!)

[image]

This happens in Simulator and on the device (via a Prerelease distributed by Apple TestFlight)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error can be caused due to invalid UTI-constants:

Make sure to double-check the **UTIs** you pass to the `documentTypes` parameter. In this case, note the blank space in the `public.composite-content` string